# How to save the selected jQuery checklist value to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery checklist to select the value after selecting value and press add button it not taking the selected jQuery checklist value, can any one guide to how to do it below is my code for showing check list

This is for showing checklist value

```
<script>
 $('#language').editable({
       pk: 1,
       limit: 3,
       source: [
        {value: 1, text: 'English'},
        {value: 2, text: 'Arabic'},

       ]
    }); 
</script>
```

HTML

```
 <div class="controls">
    <td><a href="#" name="language" id="language"  data-type="checklist" data-value="" data-original-title="Select language"></a></td>

    </div>

<button type="submit" class="contactadd">Save changes</button>
```

Here my script for getting the selected checklist value

```
$(function() {
    $(".contactadd").click(function() {

 var language=  $("#language").val();   

var dataString = 'language='+ language

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "contactsinsert.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){


    $("#flash").hide();
    }
    });

}
```

contactsinsert.php

```
<?php
$dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
$dbUsername = 'xxxx';
$dbPassword = 'xxxx';
$dbDatabase = 'xxxx';
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");

$language= $_POST['language'];

$sql_insert="insert into contact(`language`)values ('$language');
mysql_query($sql_insert);
});

?>
```

Tried but unfortunatlly its not inserting that means it not getting selected value from the checklist can any guide my how to fix this

Comment: What kind of variable is this $language? Most likely this is an array. If this is an array you need to implode it.

Comment: but it not getting an variable value,its getting null value

Comment: you didn't close the click and docuemnt ready function in jquery please watch?

Comment: First what does the JS language variable contains before the ajax post?

Comment: js language contain <script>
 $('#language').editable({
       pk: 1,
       limit: 3,
       source: [
        {value: 1, text: 'English'},
        {value: 2, text: 'Arabic'},

       ]
    }); 
</script>

Comment: No i was asking for this variable: " var language= $("#language").val();"

Answer (score 1):

First you must sanitize your `$_POST["language"]` before passing it to the sql query, to prevent sql injection.

Then you'd better to check what `mysql_query()` returns. Please check reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Add something like that:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query($sql_insert);
if (!$result) {
    // do something
}
?>
```

Oh and also check your query, maybe you should put a space before `values`.

**EDIT**

On Javascript side, I'm not sure you can use jQuery's `val()` on `<a>` tags, specially if that `<a>` tag contains some `data-` attributes. Try using `attr("data-value")` or `data("value")`:

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: its not getting the values i.e $_POST["language"] = "null"

Comment: I just edited my answer. Remember to put some logs here and there, to better debug your code!